# Is there a difference in the way the old Xbox360 reads discs and the new model?

Tags: xbox-360, hardware

I have an original Xbox360 model and my friend has the new model(the one packaged with the Kinect). When trying to play two games, blue dragon and fallout 3, the game works fine on his xbox, but on my original hardware, the xbox cannot read the discs properly. For both games, it loads the game and then either gets a disc unreadable error, or constant lag and glitches ensue. My xbox plays all other games fine, but struggles with these two. Neither of the games have a lot of scratching that would make it unplayable, because the new model can still read the games fine.

This question is more of a fundamental hardware question: Do they read games differently, or in the same way? I was thinking that maybe the slider tray and read optic are arranged a little differently in the new model, but I have never taken one apart.

Comment: I had similar problems with my PS2 when the drive was starting to fail - it would play most games, but not GTA:SA.  A new model PS2 played it fine, however.  I believe the old and new console read discs in much the same way.

Comment: The Xbox360 has used various brands of DVD-drives, and their firmwares would surely differ. This could possibly affect reading in some small way. However I believe agent86's theory to be more likely, the drive is simply starting to deteriorate from age and usage.

Comment: If you have a hard disk with enough capacity, you could install your game there, and then the disk will only be read once when starting the game. The rest will load from your HD. That might avoid those errors you're getting while playing. However, installing might be a problem too, because the whole disc has to be read and copied into your HD, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in console models. Although, they do use different disc drives in different batches. For example, a fat 360, can have a LG drive, while another fat 360 can have a Samsung drive.

You are having problems with scratched discs, because your drive is not able to read the data. Technically, it should be unplayable in such case. But, your friend is kinda lucky here, that his drive is able to read the games. There is nothing that can be done in this case, but to get the disc replaced. Also, if this happens to new games too, try getting console replaced. I had similar issue with BF3, got console replaced, and new one reads the game fine.

Answer (score -2):

No, not really. The CD reads the same.

Comment: Do you have any supporting evidence or anything?  A straight up yes or no doesn't really help anyone at all.

Comment: Obviously there is an observble difference as far as the OP is concerned. How do you account for that?